# How to delete specific contact instead of all contacts

Tags: java, android

The code deletes all contacts, but is there a way to edit cr.delete() method to delete the current contact that is selected. I have tried many other methods to try and select the current contact using getPosition, but I am no sure how that works?

```
 btnContactDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactDetailActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Confirm");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressLint("Range")
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                         try {
                            String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                            System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
                            cr.delete(uri, null, null);

                            Intent backToHomeScreen = new Intent(ContactDetailActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                            startActivity(backToHomeScreen);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I added at the end of try: catch (Exception e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             } But I know this was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete an contact via this method.

```java
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER)).equalsIgnoreCase(phone)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and don't forgot about manifest permisison

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: I have tried this method, and I do not understand how to call function deleteContact() it always requires fields inside the parentheses deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone), when you do that it don't work.

Comment: I have tried this method, and I do not understand how to call function deleteContact() it always requires fields inside the parentheses deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone), when you do that it don't work.

Comment: but their was an condition is that Phone number that return cursor of number that you choose.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me! Also creating a ContactHelper class with content to work with.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String startsWith = "";
                        Cursor cur = com.example.myan.ContactHelper.getContactCursor(getContentResolver(), startsWith);
                        int getPos = cur.getPosition();

                        if (cur.move(getPos)) {
                            ContactHelper.deleteContact(getContentResolver(),
                                    phoneCurrent.getText().toString());
                            phoneCurrent.setText("");

                            com.example.myan.HomePage.getRefresh = 0;

                            Intent backToHomeScreen = new Intent(ContactDetailActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                            startActivity(backToHomeScreen);
                        }
                    }
                });
```